# Other option than text-ellipsis

Tags: javascript, css, ellipsis

I have encountered a problem in regards ellipsis. I need the texts that I will be displaying be in ellipsis but the environment only supports until CSS2 so I can't use text-ellipsis.

Currently have a function in Javascript that loops every character of the text cuts it when it reaches a certain length and adds "..." but it's kinda slow (there are lots of texts to be in ellipsis -- too many texts to loop)

Can you suggest any other option in Javascript/CSS?

Comment: Don't loop thru every character, just do `var str = str.substring(0,length) + "..."`

Comment: The problem with this is that you will base on the length of the characters and not the width of the characters (ಥ﹏ಥ)

Comment: @MelSyGallosa `text-overfllow:ellipsis` has full browser support, take a [look](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow)

Comment: @MelSyGallosa How many characters across do allow? What's the max-height of container?

Comment: @dippas not our browser. lol

Comment: @MelSyGallosa I believe you have to have an explicit height of the containing element if you are using ellipsis, otherwise there's no need if your container expands or scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in CSS2. This CSS3 feature is well supported though going back to IE6, Chrome 4, Firefox 7 etc.  Are you sure you have to support CSS2?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow

http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: Yes. Different browser that only supports CSS2 and below (for a certain device)